# Does nodejs work with projects in other drive?

Tags: node.js, npm, parceljs

I have nodejs installed on c: and my projects are in f:

I tried a sample JS bundler package called "parcel"..

The project folder when in f: does not allow the command "npm run dev"... it throws the error "module not found".

The same folder when put on desktop... runs perfect..

Should I install node in f: drive?, uninstall it from c: and and reinstall on f: or copy the node folder in f:

**The error I get :**

```
F:\Learning & Development\node-bundlers\parcel\sample-1-kevin>npm run dev

> sample-1-kevin@1.0.0 dev
> parcel src/index.html

'Development\node-bundlers\parcel\sample-1-kevin\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\parcel-bundler\bin\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

1 more questions... if its not working because theres no node installed in f:.. how is this command running successfully "sass --watch"

Answer (score 0):

something came to my mind... the & in the folder name... "Learning & Development"... removing & solved the issue..